# How to find what sort of device is mounted at a mountpoint?

Tags: command-line, mount, samba, usb-drive, nfs

If I know the path where some sort of device is mounted, how can I get information which will determine the type of device, through a scriptable bash method?

As an example, say my mount point is `/mnt/drivex`, I know something is mounted there as I've used:

```
mountpoint /mnt/drivex
```

Which has returned the helpful message that `/mnt/drivex is a mountpoint`. This could be a USB drive, a partition on an internal drive, or a network drive such as a Samba or NFS drive.

I've tried using the fstype and source outputs of `df`:
For samba:

```
$ df --output=fstype /mnt/drivex | tail -n1
 cifs
$ df --output=source /mnt/drivex | tail -n1
 //server/SHARE
```

Internal partition:

```
$ df --output=fstype /mnt/drivex | tail -n1
ext4
$ df --output=source /mnt/drivex | tail -n1
/dev/sdb2
```

I suppose if it's a block device then I can query `lsblk` with the device name.

How can I determine the mounted drive type? Ideally  while identifying the drive type, output a simple string such as 'Samba' or 'USB', which could be saved into a variable.

Comment: You can get most of the information mentioned from `df`, but to distinguish between USB disks and internal ones is trickier: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40143/how-to-know-if-dev-sdx-is-a-connected-usb-or-hdd

Comment: df isnt really good for distinguishing usb devices. You either have to examine sys filesystem or use udisks daemon, or monitor udev system. Those are far better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install **udisks**

> sudo apt-get install udisks

then run:

```
udisksctl status
```

It will output the following:
Slimtype DVD, External (HHD) USB DISK 2.0 (or 3.0)....